# A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly error needs fixing

Tags: c#, automation, frameworks, ui-automation

I am getting this error when executing my code.

Starting class as UnitTest1:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using TestFramework;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Can_Go_To_Google_Page()
        {
            Pages.Homepage.Goto();
            Assert.IsTrue(Pages.Homepage.IsAt());
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also I have attached my startup settings:
[image: Screenshot of startup settings]

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this?
I have tried pointing the startup url to the `devenv.exe` for Visual Studio.

Comment: You need to execute unit tests from a test runner, not as an application

Comment: you don't "start" class libraries and/or unit test projects, you utilize them from something else.  Unit tests get executed through a runner, not by having the library as a start project

Comment: So what do you suggest I need to do?

Comment: Thanks for replying with a clear solution...This did fix the issue.. :) Thanks a lot guys...!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to run test project as executable (or web site) - instead you should be using VS test runner - Test -> Run -> All Tests. There are also options to run or debug individual tests as well as other test runners like one that is part of R# if you want to use alternative one.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying with a clear solution...This did fix the issue.. :-) Was treating this as a web run as you mentioned...So now I am able to run it correctly... Thanks again... :-)